# WP: latest single posts from certain categories

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering what query I should use to pull out the single latest post of specific categories.

Is something like this possible with the default attributes or should I just write my own SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need SQL or can use something like this? Because this is a self-contained loop, it can be used multiple times without conflict.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=1'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: interesting theory, I'll probably end up using this. I just wonder if writing your own SQL isn't better performance-wise